# Will running two speaker cables next to each other cause interference?

Tags: electrical, home-theater, speakers

I have a path through which I'm running some speaker cables behind some crown molding.

I would like to use the same path for two 12 gauge speaker cables for about 25 ft.

Will it cause interference to have these cables running next to each other?

Comment: None that you'd notice with your ears. Even your audiophool (oops I mean audiophile) ears - if you have those. If you connected an oscilloscope to one channel and then drove the other channel hard - then maybe you'd see something, but normal listening - no.

Comment: @brhans Thanks, the particular cables are wall-rated oxygen free, but I wanted to ask a more general question for posterity's sake.

Comment: I would agree with @brhans most audio systems are low voltage/ current  and there is not much cross talk.